# Vaadin Gird getSelectedRows() returns empty but there are selected rows

Tags: java, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I am experiencing a weird behaviour when using vaadin-gird. I am just trying to store into an arrayList of LinkedHashMaps the information from the selected rows in the grid (gRegisteredRecords). For any reason when I click on the button btnGenerateXML for the very first time, the method getSelectedRows() returns an empty list, but the second one, it works fine... why does it not work at the first attempt? here is the code..  Thanks!

```
_btnGenerateXML.addClickListener(p -> {
        ArrayList <LinkedHashMap<String, String >> alSelected = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object itemId: gRegisteredRecords.getSelectedRows()) {

            LinkedHashMap<String, String> lhmProgrammValue = new LinkedHashMap<>();

            this.gRegisteredRecords.getContainerDataSource().
            getContainerPropertyIds().forEach(propertyId ->
                lhmProgrammValue.put(propertyId.toString(),
                    this.gRegisteredRecords.getContainerDataSource()
                    .getItem(itemId)
                    .getItemProperty(propertyId)
                    .getValue().toString()));
            alSelected.add(lhmProgrammValue);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else face this issue in the future I found the problem and I would like to share the solution. The problem doesn't come with the clicklistener as I thought at the begining. The _btnGenerateXML button was linked to a Vaadin com.vaadin.server.FileDownloader object, so the elements were properly retrieved and added to the list, but the filedownloader element doesn't take them when generating the file to download. I solved this by creating a class that extends from FileDownloader and overriding the method handleConnectorRequest as follows:

```
public class CustomFileDownload extends FileDownloader {
 public interface OnDemandStreamResource extends StreamSource {
    String getFilename ();
  }

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private final OnDemandStreamResource onDemandStreamResource;

  public CustomFileDownload (OnDemandStreamResource onDemandStreamResource) {
    super(new StreamResource(onDemandStreamResource, ""));
    this.onDemandStreamResource = onDemandStreamResource;
   }

  @Override
  public boolean handleConnectorRequest (VaadinRequest request, VaadinResponse response, String path)
  throws IOException {
    getResource().getStream().setParameter("Cache-Control", "private,no-cache,no-store");
    getResource().getStream().setParameter("Pragma", "no-cache");
    getResource().setCacheTime(0);
    getResource().setFilename(onDemandStreamResource.getFilename());
    return super.handleConnectorRequest(request, response, path);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps